# Spark 1.6.2: DropDuplicates giving unexpected results

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using the dropDuplicates method to remove the duplicates entry of column A and B in the dataframe. And i am saving my resulting dataframe to empty sql table with primary key on Column A and B.  Sometimes the new dataframe has duplicates value on the column A and B

```
newdf = df.dropDuplicates(Seq("A", "B"))
newdf.write.mode("append").jdbc(url,table,prop)
```

So while inserting into the table i am getting the **java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry Exception**

Isn't drop Duplicates expected to remove all the duplicates entry on Column A and B  and how can i use batch operation under try catch such that if one batch operation fails then other batch operation go forwards instead of failing the whole job.

Answer (score 0):

`dropDuplicates` removes duplicates from the current dataset but you use `append` writer mode. There is no guarantee that dataset doesn't contain duplicates of data that is already in the table.

Comment: I am appending the current data set to an empty table.  I used append as a writer mode to append the data into an empty table with all the indexes already created.